# How do I solve this error?

Tags: views

I started facing AJAX issues on my site, due to which I was unable to create views. Googling, I found that updating the Views module might help. I added a new Views module under all/sites/modules/custom (not touching the old module at all). Now my entire site is gone and I am getting the following error:

> The website encountered an unexpected error. Please try again later.

I am not even able to login. What should I do?

I deleted the new Views module, in vain.

Comment: You should't have any module twice in your installation. You should replace your views module in place (after backup) and execute database update.

Answer (score 0):

After you've deleted that views module in the custom folder. Go into your database and empty any table that starts with "cache_" that will clear Drupal's cache and hopefully it will rediscover there is now only the original views module

Comment: How to access database and how to check error logs?

Answer (score -1):

If you have any database backup then restore it and refresh the page. Also you can use drush commands to view the error log.

Comment: How to access database and how to check error logs?

Comment: Install Drush and then go to project root path. Use the command 'drush watchdog-show'. You will see the errors as outout of this command.